# CSS in Master and regular pages

Tags: asp.net

I have some pages that use the master page and apply a theme. Some of my pages are not using master pages, instead they have individual css files linked

```
<link href="../Style/pck.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Although the css works for regular pages for most cases, the body css is taken from the theme. I do not want that. I want that the body css should be taken from pck.css.

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the pages that the CSS file is not working, have you checked to make sure that it actually loading the CSS file? (with the relative CSS link, it might not be working for pages that a deeper into your site structure).

Alternatively, I sometimes find that the  needs to be the very first thing on the page or you force some browsers into compatibility mode and all hell breaks loose when that happens.